# not getting result from youtube channel:list api

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using youtube data api (GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&categoryId=GCQ29va2luZyAmIEhlYWx0aA&maxResults=5&key={YOUR_API_KEY}). but getting no channel list in response. tried for so many categoryId's from different regionCode.

```
response from youtube api - 200

{
     "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
     "etag": "Wu2llbfqCdxIVjGbVPm2DslKPCA/ewwRz0VbTYpp2EGbOkvZ5M_1mbo",
     "pageInfo": {
       "totalResults": 0,
       "resultsPerPage": 5
     },
    "items": [
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you copy pasted the URI

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels
```

,attached an API_KEY then pasted it on your browser.

What I would recommend is use the [Try-it](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#usage) for testing then use OAuth for authorization when actually coding the app. You can see several [Quickstarts in the Youtube Guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started).

Comment: Hey already tried it on google api explorer(https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/) getting same results ?? Have tried it